# Oracle APEX - change UI language

Tags: user-interface, localization, oracle-apex

I'm trying to change the language of default UI elements in my APEX application to german:

[image: UI]

I've set the application language to german via `Shared Components` -> `Globalization`, but it has no effect on the application

[image: Globalization setting]

Is this the wrong way to change the UI elements localization? I guess there should be an easy way to change the language but I can't find any other options do it.

**EDIT:**
I noticed that this setting affects some parts of the application, like a date picker but it doesn't work for Interactive Grid labels.

**EDIT2:**
It seems like I have to use `Translation Messages` to change these internal texts. I've downloaded and installed 464 translated messages via http://translate-apex.com/ but until now I couldn't figure out how to get apex to use these messages.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Translation Messages` seems to be the right way to change the UI elements and http://translate-apex.com/ already provides a lot of translations and installation scripts.

Some translations (including all the `Interactive Grid` elements `APEX.IG.*`) are still missing and have to be made manually.

I've updated the script from http://translate-apex.com/ and added a lot of translations myself. After that the Interactive Grid elements are shown in german aswell:

[image: translated elements]

Comment: Thanks for hinting to this. One small caveat: when downloading the translation file for Apex it's necessary to supply the version information of Apex - leaving the field blank does not download the latest release as implied.